# Coda 2 and Git problems

Tags: git, coda

Yosemite, Coda 2.5.10, Git Tool Path in Coda is /usr.bin/git, I have CodeKitCodaPlugin 1.0, I have edited my core.editor to be "Coda 2 -wl1"...

This was all well and good yesterday. I can do adds and commits and some changes BUT when I try to do a "revert" on Git, I am getting the message:

There was a problem with the editor 'Coda 2 -wl1'

I have spent the past two hours trying to figure out where I've gone wrong with no joy. Has anyone else run into this problem? I am hampered in my git intruction!

Comment: What do you have when you run "git status"?

Comment: Whoa...it seems that the revert worked but I am still getting that error posted above. I am also getting a "Coda: invaild option --l". Does this mean git does not like the "l1" portion of the "-wl1" core.editor formation?

Comment: But is "-wl1" option for Coda or git?

Comment: git status:drt:explore_california allstonians02134$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
drt:explore_california allstonians02134$

Comment: I am missing a connection somewhere...git is not enjoying my use of Coda...maybe I should switch the core.editor to a less volatile platform.

Comment: I love you people!!! One simple question solved my problem:  
But is "-wl1" option for Coda or git?